# Update status in table with specific email

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a query that will update the 'status' column to 'True', but only for the users that have a `@gmail` email.

```
 Id     emailAddress           Status   dateCreated
  1     joe@gmail.com          False    1/12/2015
  2     suzanne@yahoo.com      False    6/5/2014
  3     jane@gmail.com         True     1/1/2015
```

I understand the UPDATE part, but not exactly sure how to code the %@gmail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

```
UPDATE `tablename`
SET `Status` = 'True'
WHERE `emailAddress` LIKE '%@gmail.com';
```

Comment: Like, ya know ;-) Hope all's well with you Giovanni ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- All is well in this neck of the woods. Hopefully 2015 is treating you well!

Comment: That's great John, glad to hear it :-) things are ok here. Gas prices are down, will be cruising more this summer!